# Как передать свой объект из jsp в контроллер

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

У меня есть `User`, в нем есть ссылка на `Role`, и например на странице `editUser` мне надо собрать объект `User` в контроллер spring MVC(в параметры контроллера добавляю `User user`), такие объекты как
`name(String)`,`email(String)`, `age(int)` собираются в `User` нормально, а чтобы добавить туда `Role` мне надо редактируемого User'a достать из БД извлечь его роль и засетить в новый объект `User` и только потом делать `update` в `hibernate`.

Так вот вопрос можно ли как то spring'ом сразу `User` собрать вместе с `Role` из jsp страницы?

Пробовал указать поле в верстке

```
input type="hidden" name="role" value"${user.role}"
```

но тогда вообще контроллер не находит и редиректит на страницу 400.

P.S `User` добавляю из get-контроллера в jsp, тоесть переменные `User` можно достать в jsp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как по мне, на уровне клиента это невозможно.

Как вариант, тебе нужно сперва запросом отправить id нужного объекта, а потом используя id получить его.

Я бы сделал бы это вот так

**html**

```
...
<form:form modelAttribute("user") action="..." method="post">
...
<input hidden name="id" value="${user.role.id}">
...
<button>SEND</button>
</form:form>
...
```

**Внутри метода***

```
.........@ModelAttribute("user") User user, @RequestParam("id") Integer id) {
....
Role role = (Role) session.createQuery("from Role role where role.id=:id").setParameter("id", id).list().get(0);
user.setRole(role);
....
}
```

Comment: Идея хорошая, спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

```
input type="hidden" name="role" value"${user.role}
```

Может вместо этого надо:

```
input type="hidden" name="role" value="${user.role}"
```

Comment: Спасибо, но это я ошибся в вопросе